# Failed to call CloudWatch: HTTP 400

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am having trouble in connecting.

Error is:

> ERROR: Failed to call CloudWatch: HTTP 400. Message: AccessDeniedException","Message":"User: arn:aws:sts::377696198162:assumed-role/Cloudwatchrole/i-0ea0067e154edcccf is not authorized to perform: cloudwatch:PutMetricData
>
> For more information, run 'mon-put-instance-data.pl --help'

Comment: when do you get the error ? what are you trying to do ?

Comment: facing same issue, Have you got any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the IAM role assigned to your EC2 instance (or assign a new IAM role) to have the `cloudwatch:PutMetricData` permission. Or update the role assigned to the IAM user if you are using explicit credentials.

Note this is detailed in step 3 of the documentation for the `mon-put-instance-data.pl` script [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/mon-scripts.html).

Comment: I added this in IAM role, Still facing same issue.